# Return value from another column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I’m trying to return a value from another column based on filtering of a different column in the same row grouped by another column.

I’ve tried :

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

column1<- c("A","B","C","A","B","C")
column2<- c(1,2,3,5,6,8)
column3<- c("Hat","Shirt","Pants","Shoes","Jacket","Coat")

Df<- data.table(column1,column2,column3)

Df<- Df %>%
  grouped_by(column1) %>%
  mutate(dfcol3filtered= Df$col3[Df$col2= min(df$col2)])
```

to no avail.

I would like to have dfcol3filtered return the minimum value for each grouping.

This can be done in excel but can’t figure out how to do it in r.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) solution.

```
Df %>%
  group_by(column1) %>%
  mutate(dfcol3filtered = column3[which.min(column2)]) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   column1 column2 column3 dfcol3filtered
#   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>         
# 1 A          1.00 Hat     Hat           
# 2 B          2.00 Shirt   Shirt         
# 3 C          3.00 Pants   Pants         
# 4 A          5.00 Shoes   Hat           
# 5 B          6.00 Jacket  Shirt         
# 6 C          8.00 Coat    Pants
```

The [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) solution.

```
Df[, dfcol3filtered := column3[which.min(column2)], by = column1][]
#    column1 column2 column3 dfcol3filtered
# 1:       A       1     Hat            Hat
# 2:       B       2   Shirt          Shirt
# 3:       C       3   Pants          Pants
# 4:       A       5   Shoes            Hat
# 5:       B       6  Jacket          Shirt
# 6:       C       8    Coat          Pants
```

Another [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) solution based on join.

```
Df %>%
  group_by(column1) %>%
  filter(column2 == min(column2)) %>%
  select(column1, dfcol3filtered = column3) %>%
  right_join(Df, by = "column1") %>%
  select(names(Df), dfcol3filtered) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   column1 column2 column3 dfcol3filtered
#   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>         
# 1 A          1.00 Hat     Hat           
# 2 B          2.00 Shirt   Shirt         
# 3 C          3.00 Pants   Pants         
# 4 A          5.00 Shoes   Hat           
# 5 B          6.00 Jacket  Shirt         
# 6 C          8.00 Coat    Pants
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I've been struggling to figure this out for hours! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Is there a way to expand the dplyr based solutions such that the column name is a character? E.g., `my_col <- 'column1'`?

Comment: @Baraliuh https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html